# Rxjs: Missing property error with lettable operators

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

I'm trying to use [Lettable Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md) in my import statement after upgrading to Angular 5.0.0 and I get this error.

```
ERROR in src/app/components/hero-detail/hero-detail.component.ts(32,8): error TS2339: Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<ParamMap>'.
```

I changing from `import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap"` to `import { switchMap } from "rxjs/operators"`

If fails on this code block:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.heroService.getHero(+params.get("id")),
      )
      .subscribe(hero => (this.hero = hero));
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using the lettable operator wrong. You need to use it inside of the pipe method. The link in your question shows an example

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Jota.Toledo, I rewrote the code block using pipe. Here is the working code.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.paramMap);
    this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
          this.heroService.getHero(+params.get("id")),
        ),
      )
      .subscribe(hero => (this.hero = hero));
  }
```