# RxJS lettable operators within Angular CLI

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli

Having an Angular 5 application generated with Angular CLI 1.5.0, I want to use lettable operators. However, simple usage is failing:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'foo-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: Observable<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.title = Observable.of(['Hello', 'World']).mergeMap(x => Observable.of(x.join(' ')));
  }
}
```

Produces:

> file: 'file:///c%3A/Users/drago/fooGui-1.5.0/src/app/app.component.ts'
>   severity: 'Error' message: 'Property 'mergeMap' does not exist on type
>   'Observable'.' at: '16,52' source: 'ts'

Is there anything else that has to be configured in order to use lettable operators with Angular CLI?

THanks

Comment: did you updated rxjs as well?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853898/importing-lettable-rxjs-operators

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076103/rxjs-missing-property-error-with-lettable-operators

Comment: @OleksandrBuchek: yes , i have rx 5.5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to use a `pipe` operator to invoke lettable operators, [ref](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md#usage)

```js
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
this.title = Observable.of(['Hello', 'World']).mergeMap(x => Observable.of(x.join(' ')));
```

changes to

```js
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
this.title = Observable.of(['Hello', 'World']).pipe(
  mergeMap(x => Observable.of(x.join(' ')))
);
```

BTW, don't `mergeMap` and `Observable.of` cancel out each other? So,

```
this.title = Observable.of(['Hello', 'World']).pipe(
  map(x => x.join(' '))
);
```

Comment: This was just dummy example, for testing

Comment: Indeed, but worth mentioning in case someone copies the pattern (I wouldn't have noticed, except that it came up yesterday in another question).